# Will I get a memory leak if I set an existing vector = vector<int>(num)?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

What happens if I do the following in C++:

```
vector<int> vect;
vect = vector<int>(8);
vect = vector<int>(3);
```

Will the eight integers allocated in the second line be deleted in the last line, or will they remain allocated but lost? (i.e. memory leak)

Comment: Automatic dynamic memory allocation and deletion happens internally. STL library takes care of everything for you. So no memory leak, unless there is a bug in STL library ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no memory leak. Like all well-designed resource management classes, `vector` overloads its assignment operator to do the right thing.

It will either reuse its memory; or deallocate it and allocate a new block; or, using move semantics, deallocate it and take the memory from the temporary vector being assigned from.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! So i only have to be careful when using malloc or "new", correct?

Comment: @PaoloErdman: Yes. Usually you can avoid that hassle; use containers and smart pointers to do all the tedious memory management for you.

Answer (score 0):

As laid down by the standard

```
23.2.3 Sequence containers [sequence.reqmts]
Table 100
a = il; X& Requires: T is CopyInsertable into X and
                     CopyAssignable. Assigns the range
                     [il.begin(),il.end()) into a. All existing
                     elements of a are either assigned to or
                     destroyed.
                     Returns: *this.
```

So, we can conclude that there wont be any memory leak.